# MS Access: Auto update fields in same table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Sorry but I'm not very experienced when it comes to things like this.

I have a table called "Measure Table" with the fields "ID", "Proxy" and "ProxyID".

I created a form based on this table. ID is a label pre-populated from the table. Proxy is a drop down menu with the options "For" or "From". ProxyID contains a drop down with the same numbers as ID.

I would like a user to go to a specific record in the form (say for ID:I800), select "For" from the Proxy drop down and then select ProxyID (lets say L800). For the record for L800, I want it to automatically change the proxy to "From" and the ProxyID to I800.

Is this possible in Access? 
Thanks so much for any help provided

Here is a visual of what i wnat to happen:

I want the table to look like this before the update(when the user selects "For" and "L800"):

### Record# ID Proxy ProxyID

1       I800   For   L800

2       L800

Then the table is automaticaly updated to:

### Record# ID Proxy ProxyID

1        I800   For   L800

2        L800   From   I800

Comment: Is it really called "Measure Table"? The "Table" part seems somewhat redundant. Also, your question is a bit unclear. Are you just trying to have the user change the underlying values for the table the form is bound to?

Comment: Hello yes, my Table is called "Measure_Table" I have and entry form based which allows the user to edit/insert information. They are able to edit/insert into all fields except for the "ID" field.

Comment: So when the user selects "For" in the dropdown you want it so save "From" that sounds rather confusing. Also, what is the point of having a separate ID and ProxyID. Also, do you really need to store the letter in front of the ID and ProxyID (assuming they are the same I and L letters for every row)?  Can you revise the question a bit, it is pretty confusing.

Comment: Ive made an edit to my post that will hopefully clear up your question. I dont want to save "From" for the same record, i want to save "From" for the record where ProxyID is equal to ID of another record.

Comment: Since this doesn't directly answer your question I'll put it in a comment. The simple answer is Don't do that. You really don't want to store a second row in your table that is just a flipped version of the first row when you could calculate that on the fly. Storing it twice violates a number of DB design principles and will undoubtedly create maintenance headaches for you in the future. I know you are probably firm in the belief that you need this structure, but trust me, it is a really bad idea.

Comment: Thanks JohnFx, I wasnt sure what the structure should be. There are about 20 fields in this table of the database because there is other data that goes with the "ID". So no record will be an identical flipped record. These were just the few fields that I needed to deal with. I was wondering if i should do an update query but I cant figure out in MS Access how to selct where these two fields are equal and update using only an update query.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't normalized your database tables sufficiently, which is going to create all sorts of headaches for you down the road and you will wind up with a seemingly endless number of hacky workarounds for things like this. Check out this article on normalization (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)  and do your best to get the design at least to 3NF and you will find that a lot of the issues like the one you are asking about will just go away.

Comment: Thanks. This database was given to me to make these changes but it already contained about 20 tables with 100's of records so normalizaion should have taken place during the database design process. Thanks again.

Comment: Okay. I'll post a quick and dirty solution to your original question, but understand you will need a lot of logic in your app to enforce the relationship, for example in situations where: (The referenced ID doesn't exist, the referenced id exists and the value is already set to another value, either record is deleted, either record is modified directly in the table instead of the form, etc.) It goes on and on and on, This is kinda why I was pushing for not storing the data this way, its a pain to cover all the corner cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is the gist of what you need to do to solve your immediate problem (updating the corresponding row in the other table.

Simply add an event handler to the AfterUpdate event of the form to perform the update to the other row. The code should look very similar to this...

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
  Dim RelatedID As String
  Dim Proxy As String

  If (UCase(Me.Form!Proxy) = "FOR") Then
    RelatedID = Me.Form!ProxyID
    CurrentID = Me.Form!ID

    DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE [Measure Table] SET ProxyID='" & CurrentID & "',  Proxy='From' WHERE ID='" & RelatedID & "'")

  End If
End Sub
```

**Caveats:**

As I mentioned in the comments, this data structure is a very bad idea and will create a lot of extra work for you to maintain the data integrity according to the implicit rules you are specifying as a matter of course with this design. I realize you have an existing DB to deal with, but frankly it would probably be less work to fix the DB design than maintain this one in the long run.

**Some additional considerations you didn't ask about, but are going to need to deal with:**

1. What happens if someone updates
   either of the entries in a pair
   directly in the table instead of
   using your form? There really isn't a
   good way to apply the above logic to run when
   except in the context of using the form.
2. What happens in this code if the related row doesn't exist for some reason?
3. What happens if the related row "The FROM" row is updated in the form?
4. What happens if either row is deleted from the table?

Comment: Thanks for your help! yes i realize there will be a lot of patching to do. Eventually I will redesign the database but given the timeframe I will have to do it this way. I will look in to every possible combination and write statements accordingly. I just needed a concept to get me started. You've been a great help!!